# Question regarding negative indices in tuples and lists in python

Tags: python, tuples, indices

In this program,

```
t=(1,2,3,4,5,6)   
print(t[-1:-4])
```

Why is the output:

```
()
```

and not,

```
(6,5,4)
```

This is the case with lists also. I noticed `print(t[-4:-1])` doesn't give the output as `()` but instead gives `(3, 4, 5)`

What is going on here? why can't we go backwards. Please help me I've just started python, I have no background in programming!

Comment: Ok, I realised i have to use print(t[-1:-4:-1]) and not print(t[-1:-4])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a negative step:

```
>>> t[-1:-4:-1]
(6, 5, 4)
```

Comment: Yes, i realised shortly after posting the question  :(

Comment: lol. ok, I just saw your comment :)